# Flutter notification icon not changing in Android

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am not able to change the notification icon for my Flutter app.
The icon shown is always a gray circle, like this:

[image]

[image]

I have created a transparent png file with the image for the logo in white color:

[image]

I have named it as ic_stat_push_icon.png and created the respective drawable folders:

[image]

Then I have included following lines in AndroidManifest:

```
 <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_push_icon" />
```

But no success, the notification icon is not changed, only the gray circle is shown.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a flutter package that can do this for you:
[flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

Comment: Thank you, let me try it

Comment: @ammar The plugin only shows how to change launcher or app icon but how to change app icon?